# How to create segues programatically WITHOUT changing tab bar

Tags: swift

I want to create two relationships(as segue) `UITabBarViewController` to `SecondViewController` via navigation controller. But these options depend on the selection on the `FirstViewController`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit weird, but I'll try to give you an answer based on what I understood.

- If you want to create a `UIStoryboardSegue` programmatically, you cant! Segue can only be created inside storyboard.
- If you want to transition from a viewController to another programmatically, you can use two method: `pushViewController` (of `UINavigationController`) or `presentViewController` (of `UIViewController`, that present a controller modally).

EDIT:

- if you have already set the segues in storyboard, you can trigger them using `performSegueWithIdentifier`